# Error while importing/opening project Scala Play IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

After generating project using (typesafe activator) activator new command I try to open it with IntelliJ IDEA. I meet a problem with importing that is shown below.

What can it be caused by?

[image]

I use IDEA 14.1.4 and typesafe activator 1.3.5

Comment: I've not used activator for a while. However,if there is a `build.sbt` file you can just use "file"->"open" instead of "file"->"import". Also I'm assuming you already have the IntelliJ Scala plugin installed ?

Comment: It looks like your Scala project is using a Java version that's incompatible with your Intellij project's JVM: `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. In the project settings (usually via F4 in Intellij) try setting the SDK to 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've seen this error it's because the Java version is incorrect. When you setup the settings for your project, try setting the SDK to 1.8 rather than 1.6.

[image: Intellij Import Project Settings]